# Modulus of continuity of Brownian Motion, independent of particular choice of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Suppose I can show for one Brownian Motion $(B(t))$ on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},\mathbb{P})$ that there exists a constant $C>0$ and a set $\mathcal{N}\in \mathscr{A}$ with $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{N}) = 0$ such that $\omega\notin \mathcal{N}$ implies that we can find $\delta(\omega)$ such that $0<h<\delta(\omega)$ implies that
$$|B(t+h)-B(t)|\leq C\sqrt{h\log(1/h)}$$
for every $t\in [0,1-h]$. Then how can I show that this property and constant is independent of the particular choice of Brownian motion. I.e. if $(\tilde{B}(t))$ is another Brownian Motion then we can find a new set $\tilde{\mathcal{N}}$ and bound $\tilde{\delta}$  but such that the rest carries over.

My interest in this comes from the fact that it is easy to prove the continuity condition for a Brownian Motion stemming from the Levy construction however in order to prove it for all Brownian Motions it needs to be shown to be invariant.

My attempt: Suppose that $(B(t))$ is a Brownian Motion which satisfies the continuity condition. Let $a>1$. Then we know that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{h\rightarrow 0}\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1-h}\frac{|B(t+h)-B(t)|}{C\sqrt{h\log(1/h)}}>a\right)=0.$$

So what we need now is to show that

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{h\rightarrow 0}\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1-h}\frac{|B(t+h)-B(t)|}{C\sqrt{h\log(1/h)}}>a\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{h\rightarrow 0}\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1-h}\frac{|\tilde B(t+h)-\tilde B(t)|}{C\sqrt{h\log(1/h)}}>a\right)$$
but this is where I get stuck. Any tip on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Brownian motion $B$ induces a measure $\mu$ ("Wiener measure") on the measurable space $(C[0,1],\mathcal C)$ via the map $\Phi:\Omega\to C[0,1]$ defined by $\Phi(\omega) := (B(t,\omega))_{0\le t\le 1}$. The event
$$
G:=\left\{x\in C[0,1]: \limsup_{h\to 0}\sup_{0\le t\le 1-h}{|x(t+h)-x(t)|\over C\sqrt{h\log(1/h)}}>a\right\}
$$
is an element of $\mathcal C$ and
$$
\mu(G)=\Bbb P(\Phi^{-1}(G))=\mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{h\rightarrow 0}\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1-h}\frac{|B(t+h)-B(t)|}{C\sqrt{h\log(1/h)}}>a\right) = 0.
$$
Because $\tilde B$ is also Brownian motion, *it induces the same measure* $\mu$, and so
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{h\rightarrow 0}\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1-h}\frac{|\tilde B(t+h)-\tilde B(t)|}{C\sqrt{h\log(1/h)}}>a\right) = \mu(G) =0,
$$
as well.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{C}$

Comment: Sorry, it's the $\sigma$-field of Borel subsets of $C[0,1]$.